# Import MySQL data base resource from an xml file in java web

Tags: mysql, xml, netbeans, java-web-start

I'm working in a java web project in netbeans.
I actually can connect my project to mysql using the following resource in the context.xml

/META-INF/context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/Test">
<Resource auth="Container"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        logAbandoned="true"
        maxActive="100"
        maxIdle="30"
        maxWait="30"
        name="jdbc/primary"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="120"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        url="jdbc:mysql://<<host>>/<<schema>>"
        username="<<username>>"
        password="<<password>>"
/>
</Context>
```

But I need separate the resource information to another file, how I can do it?

I tryng this:

/META-INF/context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/Test">
     <import resource="/WEB-INF/resource.xml"/>
</Context>
```

/WEB-INF/resource.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Resource auth="Container"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        logAbandoned="true"
        maxActive="100"
        maxIdle="30"
        maxWait="30"
        name="jdbc/primary"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="120"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        url="jdbc:mysql://<<host>>/<<schema>>"
        username="<<username>>"
        password="<<password>>"
/>
```